# Why have Pink shading on Google Maps as it reduces visibility & is thoroughly annoying

Tags: google-maps, ipad

Google Maps - when I use Google Maps on the iPad, pink shaded areas appear which cast an annoying shadow over what I want to view. How can I remove this function to regain an unobstructed view? It serves no useful purpose and is thoroughly annoying

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions about apps for iPads as off-topic in Web Applications SE. They might be on-topic in [apple.se].

Answer (score 1):

Unsure - but it sounds like a software fault that needs at least an update or (better) reinstall of the application. I say this as we had an instance where bits of maps would disappear leaving holes in routes and this was the solution.

Generally Google maps have poor contrast on detailled/small roads. This is a known design 'problem' that has been identified so many times it must be deliberate. We think its to force folks to follow the route marked by Google rather than using it as a map. We use Google maps for route plotting and a detailled local product for adaptive navigation (iMelway - if you're in Australia you should check them out the detail will blow you away).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/152717)